# LOAD FILE,wrong output in the last row and column

Tags: mysql

This is sql file

```
# mo.sql

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS mo;
#@ _CREATE_TABLE_
CREATE TABLE mo
(
  name CHAR(30),
  age INT,
  salary INT
);
#@ _CREATE_TABLE_

LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'moja-2001.txt' INTO TABLE mo;
```

I run it from Linux terminal

```
mysql -p cookbook < mo.sql
```

No warning,no errors.

```
SELECT * FROM mo;
+--------------------------+------+--------+
| name                     | age  | salary |
+--------------------------+------+--------+
| jova jovic               |   24 |   NULL |
| ceda prashak             |   25 |   NULL |
| toma grobar     28 20001 | NULL |   NULL |
+--------------------------+------+--------+
```

I have created txt file with `geany` text editor

```
jova jovic      24 999
ceda prashak    25 1000
toma grobar     28 20001
```

Why is salary column wrong?Why is third row wrong also?

Comment: The last row does not use the correct separators for values. I suspect the other rows separate the values using tabs and the last one uses spaces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The last row does not use the correct separators for values. I suspect the other rows separate the values using tabs and the last one uses spaces. The same for column `salary`.

Make sure you use the same separator for values. It's better to use comma (it is visible and less error prone) and use the `FIELDS TERMINATED BY` clause of the [`LOAD DATA`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/load-data.html) statement to inform MySQL about it.

Change the file to look like this:

```
jova jovic,24,999
ceda prashak,25,1000
toma grobar,28,20001
```

and import it like this:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'moja-2001.txt' INTO TABLE mo FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',';
```

Read more about the [`LOAD DATA` statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/load-data.html).